# Android Studio 4.1 Canary 1 not showing Layout Inspector Live updates

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, layout-inspector

I have installed **Android Studio 4.1 Canary** but **Layout Inspector** not showing Live updates and Processes at all. Enabled Experimental from Android Studio Settings but not happened anything.

Here is my *build.gradle* file. So everything looks ok but not showing live updates.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
            force  'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.4'
        }
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'



}
```

Comment: canary builds contains bug so it might be one of them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue fixed after updating **Android Studio** *4.1 Canary 2*. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run your Android Studio Project in API 29 or higher to see live updates of Layout Inspector of Android Studio Canary Version.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue, seems like layout inspector works with recent Android version emulators.

Didn't work with API 28 emulator but worked with an API 29 one.